# MongoDB Haskell ORM

Tags: haskell, mongodb, orm

I've been looking for an ORM that uses Haskell records to store into a MongoDB database.

HaskellWiki has [a list of some libraries](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Databases_and_Persistence) which are not necessarily ORMs.

[Persistent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-mongoDB) is the one that comes closest to what I need, but it depends heavily on Template Haskell, which I do not want. I just want plain Haskell records to be mapped to the database.

Comment: Maybe nitpicking, but ORM is a concept in OO languages right?

Comment: You could use the [mongoDB package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB) and then add a fairly thin data type conversion wrapper around it similar to the way [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) does it with something like a ToMongo and FromMongo type class.  I know it's not the answer you were looking for, but it wouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Haskell has the concept of Picklers which are sort of like ORM (and sort of not). A pickler combinator library for json/bson would be nice. :)

Comment: @mightybyte I thought of that and I still think I'd go that way if I do not find any satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Persistent without Template Haskell, you just need to define your PersistEntity instances manually. Some people are doing this currently for cases where TH isn't available (e.g., ghc-iphone).